# calculate the normal of a triangle from normals of its vertices in 3D mesh

Tags: 3d, triangulation, normals

How could I calculate the normal of a triangle from the normals of its vertices?
In the paper (Shuming Gao Hongwei Lin A robusthole-ﬁlling algorithm for triangular mesh) the authors wrote that it can be done easily, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

This is also described in the paper: "The triangle normal is the normal of the plane on which the triangle lies and can be computed as the average normal of its three vertices."